# How to multicast to specific IP addresses?

Tags: c, network-programming, multicast

I found a multicasting example at http://ntrg.cs.tcd.ie/undergrad/4ba2/multicast/antony/example.html that is simple enough.  In our network, we intend to run the client app as a daemon on each of the machines. However, the server needs to multicast files only to specific clients at a time.

Is there a way to extend multicasting to specific IP addresses?  If so, how do I extend the server code to do so?

Otherwise, I am thinking I will initially send a packet that contains the list of acceptable IPs. If the client sees that its IP is not on the list, it will simply ignore the packets that follow. This might work as I have complete control over the server and the client code.  Is this a reasonable strategy?

Comment: Why *multicast* to a specific IP? Why not just unicast to it?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Guess I need to read up on Unicast.

Comment: Your question embodies a contradiction in terms.

Comment: Don't know what you mean. The suggested software, uftp, does exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know you're only sending to a single IP, it's just as easy for the server to send to an unicast IP address as it is to send to a multicast IP address.  The socket on the client side that is set up to read multicast packets can also receive unicast packets sent to it directly.

It's a matter of setting the `sin_addr` field in the `struct sockaddr_in` you're using to pass to `sendto()`.  So if `230.1.2.3` is your multicast address and `192.168.1.2` is the specific client you want to send to, instead of this:

```
addr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("230.1.2.3");
```

You do this:

```
addr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("192.168.1.2");
```

The method of having the payload of the multicast packet containing the list of acceptable IPs is also a good solution.  This will allow you the flexibility to send to a subset of clients that are listening.  Just make sure the packet has a well defined format.  Having an application header that contains the number of IPs listed and/or the offset of the main payload is a good way to handle this.

EDIT:

If you want something off the shelf that can multicast files reliably, you can use an application I created called [UFTP](http://uftp-multicast.sourceforge.net).  It also has a unicast mode if you need that.

Comment: Thank you for your help. We have about 300 clients where we need to transfer about 20G files regularly. Unicast to each individual machine would not be performance efficent. Regards.

Comment: @Peter See my update regarding an alternate solution.